# Does every group that satisfies the maximal permutizer condition then satisfy the permutizer condition?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

The
*permutizer* of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is defined to be the subgroup generated by all cyclic subgroups of $G$ that permute with $H$,
i.e. $\langle x \in G | \langle x \rangle H = H \langle x \rangle \rangle $.
The permutizer is denoted by $P_G(H)$.

A group $G$ is said to satisfy the *permutizer condition* if $P_G(H)$ strictly contains $H$ for any subgroup $H$ of $G$.

A group $G$ is said to satisfy the *maximal permutizer condition* if $P_G(M) = G$ for any maximal subgroup $M$
of $G$.

**Question**: Can one say that every group satisfying the maximal permutizer condition must satisfy the permutizer condition ?

Comment: The converse is also true?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I don't think that's right. $S_3$ satisfies the maximal permutizer condition.

Comment: @DerekHolt : Yes, you are right I was mistaken. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Simin: In your definition of "permutizer condition", I guess you should require $H$ to be a *proper* subgroup of $G$.  This is already understood in the notion of "maximal subgroup".  (By the way, is there a reason for including the tag 'algebraic-groups'?)

Comment: I suspect that all groups satisfying the maximal permutizer condition must be solvable. I think I could prove that if I knew that no nonabelian simple group satisfied the condition. If a simple group satisfies the maximal permutizer condition, then every maximal subgroup is complemented by a cyclic group, and that seems unlikely. In fact, a subgroup of even index in a simple group cannot be complemented, but unfortunately, a simple group can fail to have a maximal subgroup of even index. A_7 is a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

An example of a group satisfying the maximal permutizer condition but not the permutizer condition is given in Example 1, page 213 of

*O. H. Kegel, On Huppert’s characterization of finite supersoluble groups, in ‘‘Proc.
Internat. Conf. Theory of Groups, Canberra, 1965,’’ pp 20-215, Gordon   and Breach,
New York, 1967.*

The group $G$ has the structure (in ATLAS notation) $2^4.(2^2 \times 2^2):(S_3 \times S_3)$. The minimal normal subgroup $2^4$ is equal to $\Phi(G)$, and $G/\Phi(G) \cong S_4 \times S_4$ satisfies the maximal permutizer condition, and hence so does $G$. But in an earlier paper,

*James C. Beidleman, Derek J. S. Robinson On Finite Groups Satisfying the     Permutizer Condition,  Journal of Algebra  191, 68-703,*

it is proved that, in a group satisfying the permutizer condition, the chief factors have either prime order or order $4$. Since $G$ has a chief factor of order $16$, it does not satisfy this condition.

Concerning Marty Isaacs'xcomment, I couldn't find an record of anyone having proved that the maximla permutizer conditino implies solvability.

Comment: I don't have access to this article, can you help me?

Comment: @Soroush Help you with what? If you ask a specific question then I will try and answer it!

Comment: i don't understand $ G $ has the structure and $ G/\Phi(G) \cong S_{4} \times S_{4} $ .

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to the paper by Kegel either! I read a description of the group somewhere and constructed it on the computer. It is constructed as a nonsplit extension of an elementary abelian group $N$ of order $2^4$ by $S_4 \times S_4$, and it turns out that $N=\Phi(G)$,

Comment: In  GAP, the group is $\mathtt{TransitiveGroup}(24,9958)$.